# Bootstrap. Can someone explain why I am getting padding above and below my image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Image is inside jumbotron, as opposed to being the background image in a stylesheet. Here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="jumbotron"> 
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/image.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"> 
</div>
```

Here is my stylesheet:

```
.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: What is the jsfiddle? Sorry

Comment: Insert you code to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Because Bootstrap's `.jumbotron` [has non zero padding](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.5/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L5006) (Learn your browser developer tools to find such trivial things on your own).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap applies the following style to 'jumbotron' elements.  You would need to override this in your own custom stylesheet.

```
.jumbotron {
  padding: 30px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

I.e.

```
.jumbotron {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Human genius!! Thanks million pal